# How to use lists of elements on Page Objects in nightwatch.js?

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver, nightwatch.js

I have a Page Object

```
export default {
  url: function () {

    return `${this.api.launch_url}/custompage`;

  },
  commands: [customPageCommands],
  sections: {
    table: {
      selector: '.table tbody',
      elements: {
        tableRows: {
          selector: 'td'
        }
      }
    }
  }
};
```

tableRows should return a list of elements. In my test I want to check the numer of rows in the table. Does anybody have a solution to this?

Answer (score 2):

There is a function called element(),you can try this in your page-object (include this in customPageCommands) :

```
    this.api.elements('css selector', ".table tbody td",function(result){
       console.log(result.value)  // this should contains rows detail
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Should be something like this with Nightwatch v2.

```
const custompage = browser.page.custompage();
const { table } = custompage.section;
table.expect.elements('@tableRows').count.to.equal(<your number>);
```